# Remove duplicate adjacent lines from file

Tags: bash, read

Say we have file like so:

```
foo1
bar
foo2
foo2
bar
bar
bar
foo3
```

I want it reduced to:

```
foo1
bar
foo2
bar
foo3
```

basically removing duplicates only if they are adjacent...I started writing a bash function but realized I have no idea how to do this:

```
remove_duplicate_adjacent_lines(){
   prev='';
   while read line; do
     if test "$line" != "$prev"; then
        prev="$line";
        echo "$line"
     fi
   done;
}
```

but the problem is the `prev` is not in scope in the while loop - is there a way to do this with bash somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what the `uniq` utility is for:

```
$ uniq <File
foo1
bar
foo2
bar
foo3
```

A good example might be bash history:

```
history | uniq
```

The above won't work because of line numbers, but this will:

```
cat ~/.bash_history | uniq
```

will remove repeated adjacent commands

From `man uniq`:

> Filter **adjacent matching lines** from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).
>   With no options, matching lines are merged to the first occurrence. [Emphasis added]

Comment: yeah I saw an answer like that - I thought it would be globally unique not "adjacently unique" - is there a way to use it as a consumer in a pipe? anyway to write my own bash function for it?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, `uniq` works in pipelines just as it is.  To wrap it in a bash function, use `myuniq() { uniq; }`

Comment: @AlexanderMills This answer is correct, and this is why when desiring a “globally unique”, you’ll see a `sort | uniq` command in order to place the identical lines adjacent to one another.